# PHP curl issue reading data from url

Tags: php, json, curl

when i try to execute below PHP code in PHP fiddle it works fine and returns NOT-Empty but when i run exactly same code in in my program via  PHP file  it returns Empty. Not sure if its my server blocking it ? any advice

```
<?php
 getCustomerTicketsByPage_1();

function  getCustomerTicketsByPage_1()
{   
$url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452";

$ch = curl_init ($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$tickets = json_decode($server_output, true);
if(!empty($tickets)){
    echo (" NOT-EMPTY ");
} else {
    echo (" EMPTY ");
}
}


?>
```

Comment: are you sure that you've curl installed on your server?

Comment: @hassan yes it is installed. i just tested it again.

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', true);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and check out if there are an error, beside what paul crovella mentioned about the last error message , and also http://php.net/curl_error

Comment: tried that as well no errors @hassan

Comment: i tried to capture browser error. when run in PHP fiddle i get _HTTP/1.1 200 OK_  and when run on server in my filename.php file  i get _Error, HTTP Status Code : 0 Headers are Response are EMPTY_ any reason why this happening.